# Azure AD B2C Direct to Identity Provider from Email

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

At the company I work for, we have our own Active Directory setup. We also have a number of external partners who each have their own Active Directory setups. We are trying to use Azure AD B2C to create a single location to sign on. Adding multiple identity providers is easy, but buttons show up for each provider and due to privacy concerns we can not allow our partners to know who else we partner with. We wish to ask for an email, and direct the user to the correct identity provider based on the domain of the email.

I know there are ways to do this, however all of the ones I have found so far are extremely convoluted. The requirements for this feel like they would be very common in many businesses, so the concept that the easiest ways to implement this require approximately a hundred steps doesn't seem right.

I'm aware of Home Realm Discovery, but like above all examples I see of it require immensely complex setups (custom policies with claims providers calling an azure function to query from a database to return the idP), we already have to setup the Identity Providers is there really no simple way to say "emails from parter1.com use this provider, emails from partner2.com use this one"? If not, could someone explain the lease complex way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this sample which collects email and does the HRD based on domain name.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern

You must use custom policy if you collect email in the B2C page.

If you collect email in the app, then you could use a User Flow with a domain_hint param. You don’t need to do any xml work, just pass a domain_hint parameter equal to the idp name in the portal.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin#redirect-sign-in-to-a-social-provider

Comment: I've seen that link, and it's only made the process more confusing for me. I see no reason this should be so complicated. We don't just copy and paste third party stuff because of security concerns, if we're going to implement a home realm discovery solution it'd be good to have information that makes it clear how it works.

Comment: Your second link says it's for social signin, I'm talking about linking multiple AD Identity Providers. Also the second link if someone goes to it without that parameter wouldn't they see the page with choice of providers. It's there's a way for a company to see the name of other companies we could have a breach of privacy/contract.

Comment: Social sign in is federated sign in. Same thing. You can copy and paste, since it uses a framework which, unless very poorly configured, cannot exactly lead to security issues. Secondly, I built that sample and I work in the product team. Thirdly, there’s a ton of resources which you can use to understand how the sample works, including the readme itself.

Comment: Yes, in the second approach, if you end up at the link with a null or invalid domain_hint, you’ll see all the providers. Again, something you can handle with custom policy by disabling all providers by default.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info. I found the info in the readme to be fairly underwhelming.  A list of "It does this then this then this" isn't super helpful for people who are starting out. I'll try it out potentially with a test app and see if it'll work for us. the other consideration is where does it query for the domain to provider mappings? Because I see nothing about this in the readme or the policy. It'd be great it if would pull from the list of Identity Providers, but if it works it'll give us a starting point. I'll test it tomorrow before accepting the answer if it works for us.

Comment: The metadata of each IdP contains a list of domain names for which it will become enabled for. That list is compared to the extracted domain name from the users email. The result bring only a single Idp remains enabled thus sending the user to that IdP, HRD.

Comment: Seems to be working fine so far, so thank you very much.